Realtek RTL8723BE Wireless card not working in Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
I have an HP laptop (Hp 15) with Realtek RTL8723BE WIFI card after upgrading the kernel to 6.2.11-060211-generic. The WIFI connection keeps getting Dropped after some time like 15-20 minutes with message Activation of network connection failed and then it won't connect no matter what I do expect the only option left is to restart.

Does this answer your question? How do I get a Realtek RTL8723BE wireless card to work?

Which Kernel came with your Ubuntu 22.04 installation and how did you upgrade to Linux kernel 6.2?

@zx485 this answer not working
"Unable to locate package rtl8723au-bt-dkms" and github repo not exist

@xangua,  don't remember Which Kernel came with my Ubuntu 22.04 installation it was installed very long time ago and I just type update & upgrade commands, next day wifi suddenly stoped I trace the changes and got the current  kernel installed
"uname -a" output "Linux essam-goda 6.2.11-060211-generic #202304131639 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Apr 13 16:45:29 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"

I agree, on a closer look, the "duplicate" question is quite dated. It would be a good idea to use this question for more up-to-date answers relating to the 6.xx version of kernels. But I cannot vote to re-open.
